# -> symbol in a function header

Tags: python, xgboost, type-hinting

I was trying to run [this code](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/examples/cat_in_the_dat.html#sphx-glr-python-examples-cat-in-the-dat-py) in a kaggle notebook (my laptop has no gpu).
When running the cell with load_cat_in_the_dat, the kaggle notebook throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-4269c4a7bc86> in <module>
----> 1 def load_cat_in_the_dat() -> tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]:
      2     """Assuming you have already downloaded the data into `input` directory."""
      3 
      4     df_train = pd.read_csv("./input/cat-in-the-dat/train.csv")
      5 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

1. I've searched, but I couldn't find the meaning for the `->` in the `def load_cat_in_the_dat() -> tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]:` line of code. What is this?
2. Have you had any experience with directly using categorical features in an xgboost model? Does the performance improve significantly when compared with one-hot-encoding?

Comment: The `->` is a type annotation. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

You might be running an older version of python in which the `tuple[x, y]` syntax isn't supported yet. In this case you can do `from typing import Tuple` and then use `Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series]` instead.

Comment: Bottom line: you need to use a newer Python version, at least 3.9+, to run this code.

Comment: `->` is used for type hinting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html